# Angular ng-href javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I need to set href to Javascript function.  When I click it, nothing happens, but when I hover over link it displays:

```
unsafe:javascript:ShowManagementdDiv('65','a60f2a16-267e-418d-bb14-d88de3a33b5f','0');
```

The table data is built dynamically in my angular controller:

```
contractorService.getemrtabulation()
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.emrcolumns = data.EMRTabulationColumns;
                    repeatRow = '<td align="center" valign="middle" style="background-color:Transparent;border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;padding:5px;white-space:nowrap;"><a class="IncidentColumn" ng-href={{e.hyper}}>Click Here to Review EMR Document</a></td>';
                    firstRow = '<td>EMR Document</td>';
                    for (i = 0; i < $scope.emrcolumns.length; i++) {
                        repeatRow = repeatRow + '<td>{{e.' + $scope.emrcolumns[i].vchAssociatedDetailColumn + '}}</td>';
                        firstRow = firstRow + '<td>' + $scope.emrcolumns[i].vchColumnHeaderText + '</td>'
                    }
                    firstRow = '<tr>' + firstRow + '</tr>';
                    $scope.emrdetail = data.EMRTabulationDetail;
                    angular.forEach($scope.emrdetail, function (value, key) {
                        value.dteExpirationDate = convertDate(value.dteExpirationDate);
                        value.dteDateCompleted = convertDate(value.dteDateCompleted);
                        value.dteEffectiveDate = convertDate(value.dteEffectiveDate);
                    });
                    angular.forEach($scope.emrdetail, function (value, key) {
                        contractorService.getimage(value.EMRDetailID, value.dteEffectiveDate)
                    .success(function (data) {
                        $scope.emrdetail[key].hyper = data;
                    });
                });
                    $scope.emrTable = '<table>' + firstRow + '<tr style="text-align:center" ng-repeat="e in emrdetail">' + repeatRow + '</tr></table>';
                    firstRow = '';
                    repeatRow = '';
                });
```

I use this to call it in the html:

```
<div class="row row-relative">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div>{{emrQuestion.EMRTabulationID}}{{emrQuestion.vchTabulationSequenceLetter}}.&nbsp;{{emrQuestion.vchClassPropertyName}}</div><br />
            <div dynamic="emrTable"></div><br /><br />
        </div>
    </div>
```

The function is in a `<script>` tag on the page:

```
function ShowManagementdDiv(imageTypeID, Guid, selectedYear) {
    var TargetWidth = 950;
    var TargetHeight = 670;
    bModalPopupActivated = true; window.clearTimeout(t);
    DisplayModalDivExitWithClickSave('box', TargetWidth, TargetHeight, 'http://localhost/PECIMS/DocumentManagement.aspx?eid=' + imageTypeID + '&Edx=' + Guid + '&y=' + selectedYear, 'Close', 'Click to close window.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
}
```

Here is the C# code that creates the link:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetImage(int emrDetailID, string docDate)
        {
            var columns = await CommonClient.GetEMRTabulationColumnsForClusterID(876);
            var getcolumn = columns.FirstOrDefault(c => c.EMRTabulationColumnID == 1);
            int? imageTypeId = getcolumn.EdataFileImageTypeID;
            UserInfo.intDocumentManagementMode = 13;
            UserInfo.intPerspectiveCompanyID = UserInfo.intMajorID;
            UserInfo.intPerspectiveCompanyTypeID = UserInfo.intMajorCompanyType;
            UserInfo.SegmentID = emrDetailID;
            UserInfo.dteDocumentDate = DateTime.Parse(docDate);
            var token = await CompanyClient.SaveRecallData(UserInfo);
            string strPathAndQuery = Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
            string strUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(strPathAndQuery, "/");
            string LinkToImagesApp = "";
            LinkToImagesApp = AppendProtocolAndHostHeadersPathToWebConfigPath("LinkToImagesApplication");
            string javaLink = strUrl + LinkToImagesApp + "/DocumentManagement.aspx?eid=";
            string docLink;
             string address = "javascript:ShowManagementdDiv('" + imageTypeId + "','" + token + "','0');";
             return Json(address, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I am assuming that the issue is that Angular deems the Javascript as `"unsafe"`.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you set up a fiddle? Why don't you use ng-click...

Comment: I'm using functions that were setup in Asp.net webforms and they use a js file called ModalDiv.  I'm not sure how I would use ng-click for this.

Comment: I don't think this is the way to set angular up as a frontend framework. Are you even sure the function is in scope? you should also make this a directive.

Comment: Thanks.  You're probably right, but your solution is above my knowledge.  I'm pretty new to Angular, MVC and Javascript.  I have been charged with recreating functionality of an old webforms app into MVC and Angular.

Comment: Why are you even building html strings? Let angular manage the dom from templates based on scope models. All you focus on then is setting up the data models. Only use back end as a data API. Asking for headaches mixing 2 frameworks and template engines to create the DOM

Comment: I have no choice with the html strings because of how the information is stored in the database and the format in which they want it displayed.  The old app built tables dynamically by adding one row at a time to a DataTable and displaying in a grid control.

Comment: Certainly you have control....use `ng-repeat` in view and get rid of the string building. That's not how you use angular

Comment: There is ng-repeat in the string.  You haven't seen the data.  The column headings and the detail or not in the same table.  The data is a mess.

Comment: if there is ng-repeat in the string you'll probably have to use $compile service, no? to actually render the template after-the-fact

Comment: Yes.  If you look at the html the string is displayed using "dynamic" which calls compile service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the Javascript function in my href I had to add the following to my app.js file:

```
app.config([
    '$compileProvider',
    function ($compileProvider) {
        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension|javascript):/);
    }
]);
```